# How to rename quick access shortcut without renaming the original folder name?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

When I try to rename one of these Quick access shortcuts,...

[image]

, the original folder name are renamed also.

What I'm looking for is to rename the shortcuts without renaming the original folders names.

OS: Windows 10

---

This question isn't a duplicate of [Windows 10: Rename pinned items in Windows Explorer's Quick Access](https://superuser.com/questions/947292/windows-10-rename-pinned-items-in-windows-explorers-quick-access). This question is asking about *how not to rename the original folder with the same name of its Quick Access shortcut on being renamed*, while the other question is asking about *the existence of the rename feature itself — not its relation with the original folder name*.

Comment: Only workaround is to make directory junctions, as in post [Windows 10: Rename pinned items in Windows Explorer's Quick Access - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/947292/windows-10-rename-pinned-items-in-windows-explorers-quick-access)

Answer (score 10):

Windows does not have the ability to rename Quick Access pinned items,
so one needs to rather use the workaround of pinning
a symbolic link to the folder.

The procedure is described in the article
[Rename Quick Access pinned folders in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/rename-quick-access-pinned-folders-in-windows-10/)
in detail and with screenshots.
Here is the bare method :

1. Unpin from Quick Access the folders you wish to rename.
2. Create a new empty folder, for example `c:\Users\your_name\Pinned Folders`.
3. Open a new Command Prompt (CMD) window and type the following command per each folder to pin:
   `mklink /J "%userprofile%\Pinned Folders\New Name" "c:\path\folder to pin"`
   (`%userprofile%` is same as `c:\Users\your_name`)
4. Right click the items in `%userprofile%\Pinned Folders` and pin them to Quick Access.

Comment: Thanks for this good approach! But for each folder that I need to pin, I do this procedure, this would take a lot of time, also the shortcuts won't be portable to other computers unless the symbolic link is made first.

Comment: You could automate some of the creation of the script to run by using batch commands. You could keep the batch files for later use on other computers.

Comment: I tried to do this on a network drive and I got an error that "Local NTFS drives are required for this operation". Is there a workaround for networked drives?

Comment: This [should work](https://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows).

Comment: The network drive issue can be resolved by 1. using /D instead of /J, 2. running in an administrator shell, and 3. using the complete path (rather than %userprofile%). But this  still doesn't work for me; the entry in Quick Access is always renamed to its source name regardless of what name I give the link.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for folders that are under version control. I lose the vc information of the original folder.

Comment: Did exactly this (and also tried just creating the link using Windows Explorer context menu), and then pinned the link as shown - it always resolved immediately to the linked path, and just used the final directory name. In other words, this method didn't work at all for me - it did exactly the same as pinning the original path.

Comment: How to hide the arrow in the lower left corner of the symbolic linked folder icon?