# Windows quick access shortcut for svn trunk folder

Tags: svn, windows-10-quick-access

I want to rename the quick access folders of my svn repos, because they'd all be called "trunk". I followed the answer from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1125557/how-to-rename-quick-access-shortcut-without-renaming-the-original-folder-name), and everything seems to work. I have the folder with all the links, and I can drag them to the quick access bar.

So as an example, the actual folder is located at `c:Users/me/files/svn-folder/trunk/` and the link is at `c:Users/me/quickAccessHack/fake-trunk`. Both Windows Explorer and WSL bash now navigate to the link, rather than the original folder. I assume this is by design.

However, all these folders are svn version controlled, and this seems to go haywire with this hack. TortoiseSVN is now convinced that the folder is not version controlled at all. I thought, okay, I use WSL anyway, let's do it there. Svn status and svn info do still work via WSL, but as soon as I want to write anything to the folder, I get `svn: E200030: sqlite[S10]: disk I/O error`.

If I navigate to my *real* folder via WSL, svn works as intended. What I don't understand is that the folder address changes with the link, too. So the shortcut isn't really a shortcut TO a place, but rather substituting the place with another place. I assume this is why svn breaks? How can I avoid this?

I found [this question on SO on symbolic links in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056092/what-happens-if-i-add-a-symbolic-link-to-subversion), but I think my issue is not that a symbolic link is *within* my svn repository, but rather that the repository itself is linked.

The only way to fix this issue is by not linking the trunk directly, but rather the parent folder which contains branches and trunk. This means however I always have to navigate to the trunk first, which I want to avoid. I appreciate any help or explanation.